# Is there a file manager that handles smartly when moving folders that correspond to ZFS datasets?

Tags: filemanager, zfs

All my Linux systems (Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04, server and desktop alike) have root-on-zfs and data on one or more ZFS pools.

Of course data need to be shifted around often, for instance with mc or dolphin or such.

The following use case and question assumes data is moved around within a zpool (not between different zpools).

All filemanagers I tries so far (mc, thunar, dolphin, nemo and some more) you can not differentiate which folder is just a folder, and which one is a zfs dataset.

So if you want to move a folder which in fact is a dataset, all filemanagers start to create a plain folder on the target an copy all files into it.

But if the target folder itself is also a dataset, I expect the filemanager to simply rename the source dataset accordingly - this would be much faster, smarter and for me the more reasonable operation.

Use case example, dataset structure before, mountpoints equal the dataset name:

```
zp/media/movies/scifi
zp/media/movies/crime
zp/media/movies/classic
zp/media/movies/nature
zp/media/new/anime
```

Now open mc, select /zp/media/new/anime and move it to /zp/media/movies. I assume the target does not already exist, neither as folder nor as dataset at that position.

Result: mc creates a folder /zp/media/movies/anmime and moves on file after the other to that position. On the end it tells that it could not remove /zp/media/new/anime (because it is a dataset, which can not be removed by rm).

Expected behavior: literally `zfs rename zp/media/new/anime zp/media/movies/anime`

Let's also assume for now that the filemanager has permissions to modify ZFS datasets.

If the target already exists of course the only option is a `mv`operation.

**==> Is there a filemanager that is aware of ZFS and able to handle datasets as described above?**

I know there is a [abandoned and incomplete project named zc](https://github.com/manoeldesouza/zc) "zfs commander" (console app) which also has a GTK+ port named [zyggy](https://github.com/manoeldesouza/zyggy) - but I look for something that is actively maintained.

PS: It does not hurt, if it is aware of snapshots as well.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I would advice you use official ZFS tools for dataset manipulation. It seems the functionality you want is to rename datasets and their mountpoints.

Comment: I am confused. A ZFS dataset is simply a filesystem that is mounted over some directory. Now, let's assume there are datasets `/vol/ds1` and `/vol/ds2`, what exactly do you mean by "both target and source folders are datasets"? Is it something like `mv /vol/ds1 /vol/ds2`? If that's the case, then how do you expect `ds1` to be renamed to `ds2` if `ds2` already exists? Besides, moving a mounted directory should result in `EBUSY` error, do you expect it to be unmounted? What about existing load? What you are asking seems to be some very specific workflow is not "reasonable" for the general case.

Comment: What is the purpose you expect in a GUI usage?

Comment: If the constraints allow a folder move operation be translated to a dataset rename operation - why not do it that way. Or at least ask: "hey, source is a dataset and we could rename it to get it done, should we?"

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a filemanager that is aware of ZFS and able to handle datasets as described above?

No. Each ZFS is a separate filesystem. `mv` (or any other tool) can not move block pointers.from one filesystem to another. Filemanagers use the regular commands to move and copy files.

If it was possible we would already be able to do it. I found a topic on [openzfs](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/2991) stating that there are 3 big issues that makes this a problem: hard links, snapshots, and it can not be a directory. And that was way back in 2014, 2015.